# Selecting a row from Jtable and get that row data to a another form window in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

[image]

I created following forms for Inventory management module.

Functionality be done is;

**When I select a row from Drug List window and click Select, the relevant ItemID and Item Name want to add in the Edit inventory window in relevant text Fields.**

I set variables access modifiers as private and did coding. But Is't correct. Anyone know any method for code above functionality?

Comment: *"I tried to do that.."*  Try to ask a (specific) question.  And for better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example) of your best attempt.

Comment: [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..

add two jlabel on drug list jframe..

1)itemIDlbl

2)itemNamelbl

then..

**Note: DT is jtable variable name.**

```
DT.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
               itemIDlbl.setText(DT.getValueAt(DT.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
                 itemNamelbl.setText(DT.getValueAt(DT.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
            }
        });
```

now you have stored selected row items in jlabel. now you can simple pass it to edit inventory..

```
private void selectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

       String id=itemIDlbl.getText();
       String name=itemNamelbl.getText();
        EditInventory ei =new EditInventory();
    ei.get(id,name);
    this.dispose();
    ei.setVisible(true);

    }
```

make a method in edit inventory to accept values..

```
 public void get (String id,String name)
    {
        id_txt.setText(id);
        name_txt.setText(name);

    }
```