# How to pass the selected data of jtable to another jframe without closing them

Tags: java, swing

For First time I am raising the issue in this site . I am not able to pass the data from one JFrame to another  JFrame. On button click I am getting the Access Sequence .
 Click on the Jtable row from the access Sequence Jframe , the selected data should be loaded to the jTextfield1 without reloading the previous frame .

I have coded as

on Access Sequence jTable MouseClick as

```
table.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e){

            if(e.getClickCount()==2){
                int row=table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                final String str=table.getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
                System.out.print(str);
                new ChangeAccessesOverview.jTextfield1.setText(str);
                dispose();
            }

        }
    });
```

I am not able setText for jTextField1 which is present in previous frame.

Comment: already have answered that question..
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601757/selecting-a-row-from-jtable-and-get-that-row-data-to-a-another-form-window-in-ja/31602325#31602325]

Comment: I got the answer . But i am looking for a code which Dispose only the Access Sequence and pass the value to the Main Frame without reloading  changeAccessOverview.setVisible(true);